# WordPress Theme Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, drop-down-menu, themes

My website was working fine until the other day. I don't know what's happened but the dropdown system for everything has stopped working completely - even the Admin bar.

When I open up the JavaScript Console in Google Chrome when I'm on [the site homepage](http://thejailbreaker.co.uk), I get this message for each dropdown item:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'on'...
```

I don't know how to fix this, I've looked everywhere. Would it be in the themes "Header.php" file? If so, whereabouts?

Comment: You're using jQuery 1.4.4 but (at least) sharedaddy expects 1.7+

Comment: What's sharedaddy and where would I change the jQuery script source? - Thank you

Comment: The script (sharedaddy.js) which fails because of the missing `.on()` method

Comment: Questions on Stack Overflow need to contain an [mcve] in order to remain open. If you can edit some relevant code into this post, that would help it remain open, though I appreciate it is old. Alternatively, you may delete it, since as it stands the problem is not reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem! I wen into the plugins section of Wordpress and disabled "LikeLocker". The only problem is, now I've got to go into the plugins code and try to figure it out haha.

Thank you anyway!